# Laravel swiftmailer does not take info from .env

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I have got a strange error on Laravel 5. After customizing my registration/login, adding necessary columns to users database, I decided to fix password resetting system, so, first, I connected my project to my SMTP account on Gmail and tried to send validation links, test emails, etc. Just like that:

```
Mail::raw('Test', function ($message)
{

    $message->from('email@gmail.com', 'Danielius');

    $message->to($request->input('email'));

});
```

Everything worked just fine.

But then I tried to do a password reset and got this error:

`Cannot send message without a sender address`

I did some googling and found out that such problem may occur if mail is badly configured, but how can it be if I was able to send email manually? I am working on localhost. Everything is configured in .env file. Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE** Okay, I have fixed it, but now I can not connect to my gmail account, getting:

`Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.`

I have enabled insecure apps and also made two-step authentication, so what may be a problem? Thanks again!

Comment: where are you authorizing with your smtp creds? i don't see that in code above.

Comment: @ATechGuy hello, I kinda fixed it. Could not make the default password reset system work, so just made a new method where it sends mail and used it instead of the default one. With my `Mail::send()` everything works just perfectly. Have no idea what was wrong.